# Why operations in tropical geometry defined as it is?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tropical-geometry

I'm a deep learning researcher, and these days studying algebraic geometry for my research and for personal interest.

I'm noob to this field, and I found a research area called **tropical geometry** (TG).

In TG, multiplication and summation is defined as:

$$x\oplus y = \max\{x,y\}$$
$$x\odot y= x + y$$

I don't get the motivation of these operations.

Up to my opinion, these operations makes sense if we define

$$x\oplus y = \lim_{t\to\infty}\log_t(t^x+t^y)=\max\{x,y\}$$

$$x\odot y = \lim_{t\to\infty}\log_t(t^x\cdot t^y)=(x+y)\lim_{t\to\infty}\log_tt=x+y$$

But I can't get why operations should defined like this.

Is there any motivation or motivating example?

Comment: The justification for defining the operations is indeed the log-exp limit you mention. This is (apparently) useful for studying the large-scale behaviour of algebraic varieties.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thx. My exact question was whether there exist any motivating example.

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/155464/305862) is of interest for you ? or this one : https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-significance-of-tropical-geometry