# Why tropical geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tropical-geometry

In my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4450715/why-operations-in-tropical-geometry-defined-as-it-is), I wondered why operations should be defined as it is in tropical geometry (TG).

Now my second question is, why mathematicians had to consider and developed TG and TG machineries?

As we can check in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612129), there are tropical version of various algebraic geometrical concepts like Riemann-Roch Theorem.

But does this analogy is all? Is there any inevitable relationship between tropical geometry and algebraic geometry?

I believe there should be more than analogy, and wants to know motivation of TG.

Thanks.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83624/why-tropical-geometry

Comment: @HansLundmark Thx!!!!